# How to add custom fields to devise 3 and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to add custom fields to my user signup and edit pages, I used to do one way, but with new rails and devise it doesn't seem to work. I tried reading other threads and readme from devise git, but no luck!

Here is my registrations_cotroller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name, :phone, :cpf, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u|u.permit(:name, :phone, :cpf, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)}
  end

end
```

and here is my view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

And this is the error I get:

> NoMethodError at /users/sign_up
>
> undefined method `phone' for #

Do I need to change any other file in order to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Check your application_controller.rb, make sure that you don't have devise params in there already which are overriding

Comment: @trh I checked and there's nothing there related to devise. Any other suggestion on what might be the problem?

Comment: @trh I found the problem and I feel stupid now. I forgot to add the migration to my db. Thanks anyways!